# (Android)After Researching: guidance with saving User's Input into a text file, even after the application is closed. However, Something is wrong

Tags: android, android-studio, text-files, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream

I am asking this question after doing some research about saving user's input into a text file. I would like to save it even well after user closes the application. However, It saves and display the input ONLY when application is at run time. So After it restarts, the data that user input does not exist.

This code below is where I write the user's input into a textfile "stuff.txt":

```
   public void sendActivity(View view) {
    EditText activityTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.users_activity);
    String activity = String.valueOf(activityTitle.getText());
    try {
        FileOutputStream input = openFileOutput("stuff.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter (input));
        write.write (activity);
        write.close();
   }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Your activity is added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent sendData = new Intent(this, listToDo.class);
    startActivity(sendData);
}
```

The code below is where I read the "stuff.txt"

```
  protected ArrayList<String> dataRead (){
    FileInputStream fis;
    ArrayList <String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        fis = openFileInput("stuff.txt");
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String activity;
        while ((activity = bis.readLine()) != null){
            data.add (activity);
        }
    }
    catch  (Exception e) {
    }
    return data;
}
```

**[Goal]: input: "hello" (1st running), "hi" (2nd running)-- output: "hello", "hi"
**[now]: output: "hi"